# How to configure in the trust-store in client service and configure the key-store in server service in spring reactive application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two services one is server service and another one is client service.

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certs/server-keystore.jks

server.ssl.key-store-password= password

These details I configured in the server service.

server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:certs/client-truststore.jks

server.ssl.trust-store-password=password

and These trust-store details I configured in client service.

1. I need to call the client service any one API call in the server service using WebClient.
2. and also need input on how can I test in Postman.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.